# JavaScriptのif文の中身を書くところ

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
if(a < b) { // a < b なら中身を実行
  a = b;
}
```

こんな感じに書いてあったんですけど、`if(a < b) { // a < b なら中身を実行` の中身をどこに書けばいいんですか？

Answer (score 1):

このプログラムにおいて「a < b なら中身を実行」の「中身」とは `a = b;` の行のことです。

if 文の後に中かっこ { } で囲われた部分がありますが、a < b が成り立つならこの中かっこに囲われた部分が実行されます。

たとえば a に b を代入する `a = b;` の他に、実行されたことを出力する `console.log("executed!");` を実行させたいなら、下のように書けます。

```
if (a < b) {
  a = b;
  console.log("executed!");
}
```